# Methodology to identity any overlapping/duplicate Geolocation POIs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, geospatial

I'm trying to build a map for to show spending. Our vendor data is not entirely clean and we could have 5  or 6 definitions of the same place. We also have hierarcial POI issues also (think gives an entire shopping strip geometry instead of individual store). I'd like to know if there are any common algorithms to identity duplicates at the geometry object level.

My data are in Geopandas Dataframes with a 2-D polygon to represent a place, and other meta data (i.e. store name, category, etc.). Sometimes it will come with an address but not always and not a very consistent postal format.

I'm working in Python specifically, but open to any suggestions, not exactly limited to Python. Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: This is probably the article you're looking for (only the **overlap** part):

https://medium.com/@achm.firmansyah/an-approach-for-checking-overlaps-and-gaps-in-polygons-using-geopandas-ebd6606e7f70

Comment: If it doesn't help, could you give some more info on the data? 

Specifically, if two stores' polygon are overlapping or really close (within 10m) from each other, is it save to assume that they are duplicates? 

If it is the case, you can take the polygons' centroids and measure the distances from each other.